# Anyone tried Solace? Solace - a multilingual support platform

Tags: python, open-source, platform

Has anyone tried Solace yet?

"Solace is a fully open-sourced multilingual support and knowledge exchange platform written in Python."

Just wanted to know your experience. Are there any other such platforms available in open source?

Comment: That is open source, it's licensed under the BSD license. http://opensource.plurk.com/Solace/License/

Answer (score 3):

[This one](http://github.com/cnprog/CNPROG) [seems better](http://www.cnprog.com/).

Comment: cnprog.com doesn't work, github repo has no README even.

Comment: @yentsun: The Git repository looks fine. As for the website, check http://web.archive.org/web/20100710150418/http://www.cnprog.com/, the latest snap (http://web.archive.org/web/20110430174128/http://cnprog.com/) suggests you visit http://www.osqa.net/.

Comment: Thanks! osqa.net - very impressive.

Answer (score 2):

I already set up my own server. Solace seems great.

Answer (score 2):

We just started using it at our company. You get what you pay for. Feels like a weekender project. Gets the job done, but lacks the polish of Stack Overflow. The documentation is weak. I find it ironic that Plurk doesn't run an instance of Solace to field support questions for Solace. If they do they don't advertise it.